# How to Find Count After Join in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I join multiple tables with:

```
session.query(R, RR, RRR).join(R).join(RR).all()
```

I tried:

```
session.query(func.count(R, RR, RRR)).join(R).join(RR)
```

However, this does not appear to be the correct approach to determining the count from tables.

I could do

```
len(session.query(R, RR, RRR).join(R).join(RR).all())
```

but ideally, I won't have to do my counts in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after `COUNT(*)`, below should work:

```
q = (session
     .query(func.count().label("cnt"))
     .select_from(R)
     .join(RR)
     .join(RRR)
     )
r = q.scalar()
```